# Play Framework Ebean BigDecimal fraction

Tags: playframework, h2, ebean

I am using the Play Framework with Ebean and H2 database.

The problem is, the `BigDecimal` results in the DB script as:

```
  sum                       decimal(38),
```

but what I want is:

```
  sum                       decimal(38,2),
```

I already tried to define the value in the model like that:

```
    @Digits(integer=6, fraction=2)
    private BigDecimal sum;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use **@Column(precision = 38, scale = 2)** annotation. @Digits annotation seems to be for validation purposes, not for DDL generation.

Also 38 looks like overkill. Are you gonna store all money on earth? :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll try that :)

Haha, no it was the standard value so I was fine with that 
but yes I would like to